# how to achieve the following effect in imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, gm, node-imagemagick, node-gm

I am trying to get sketch effect and i have the imagemagick command line code as follows

```
convert 1.jpg -colorspace gray   ( +clone -blur 0x8 \) +swap -compose divide -composite  -linear-stretch 2%x20%  cousincs.jpg
```

I am using gm module and I tried to extend gm,however it is not not accepting parenthesis, failing to recognize -linear-stretch resulting in two blurred images instead of one. I tried node-imagemagick native and wizardry but unable to achieve the desired functionality. Can anyone let me know how can I achieve this. Thanks in advance

Here is the code i tried with gm

```
  var dir = __dirname + '/kar/';
  var newName=uuid.v4()+".jpg";
  imageMagick("2.jpg")
  .clone()
  .swap()
  .compose('divide')
  .composite()
  .write(dir+newName, function(err,data){console.log("error is ",err)});
```

Here is the args.js

```
  proto.clone = function clone () {
  return this.out("\( +clone -blur 0x8\)");
  }

 proto.swap=function swap(){
  return this.out("+swap");
}

proto.composite=function composite(){
  return this.out("-composite  -linear-stretch 2%x20%")
}
```

Comment: Untested, and a bit inefficient, but try `convert 1.jpg -colorspace gray -blur 0x8 1.jpg -colorspace gray -compose divide -composite <linearstretchthing> result.jpg`

Comment: Thanks Mark!! I am able to implement this using imagemagick npm but not gm. It helped.